# Sharing node_modules chunks across builds (webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-modules

I want to setup a webpack.config file that is able to dynamically accept entry points, and build them, whilst outputting all of the used node modules as chunks. So for example if we had:

```js
// main-a.js
import { a, b, c } from 'node-module-a'
import hello from 'node-module-b'
```

I'd like to have an output folder that contains:

- main-a.js
- node-module-a.js
- node-module-b.js

Note that `node-module-a.js` should contain all of its dependencies as well, so that node-module-a contains the entire imported library. So then if I used the same webpack configuration file with another entrypoint as shown:

```js
// main-b.js
import { b, d } from 'node-module-a'
import there from 'node-module-c'
```

My output folder would now contain:

- main-a.js
- main-b.js
- node-module-a.js
- node-module-b.js
- node-module-c.js

Loading both `main-a.js` and `main-b.js` from the browser should work.

### What I tried

I tried achieving this with the `optimisation.splitChunks` option, to detect the node_modules and to place them into their own chunks. This seems to have a few issues:

- It doesn't reliably seem to work with async modules (but that could just be a misconfiguration)
- On production builds, the modules from the first build are not recognised by the second build

Is there a better way to achieve this? I get the hint that this isn't what splitChunks is designed for. The purpose here is to be able to use the node_modules that I've installed almost like modules, since I will have lots of different entry points, and don't want to include any of the node modules code in those entry points.